# Right Bar Button Image Way Too Big - Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar

In my app I have a `settingsVC` and a settings icon that when clicked on takes you to the user preferences. The only problem is the settings icon is not scaling, as seen in the upper right:
[image]

I've tried

```
let moreButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
moreButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "settings-icon"), for: .normal)
moreButton.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: moreButton)
```

which doesn't work. I also tried to set the image in the `storyboard`, with no better effect. The strange thing is that when I open the image in an editor, it doesn't show it distorted; and the width and height is the same.
Any ideas how to get the image to be normal?

Comment: This code seems correct. You might try setting `adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory` to `false`. If you have some code that manipulate the `navigationItems` then it would be better to include that in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may work with you

```
let moreButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "settings-icon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(go))

self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([moreButton], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
moreButton.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
```